# Problem with LoadLibrary and encrypted DLL

Tags: qgis, python, dll, encryption

I'm using QGIS and I try to implement a new function into my plugin. For that I need to use a DLL which is encrypted. In my C++ test application I don't have any problems to use that DLL with LoadLibrary. In my plugin I don't have any problems too until my dongle is connected. If no dongle is connected an error message is displayed because DLL can't be decrypted. This is correct too, but LoadLibrary gets no return and hangs. I don't have this behavior in my C++ test application. QGIS does not react too. Is this a general problem of Python? Is there a possibility to fix this behavior?